# python 'the specified module could not be found'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

so I have python 3.61

I installed Pygame 1.9.3-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl, which I opened with 7zip and extracted to lib/site-packages/.
and I got the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       import pygame
>     File "C:\Users\my name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pygame__init__.py", line 141, in 
>       from pygame.base import *
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I'm running 64 bit python, used the latest available updates of both python and pygame, and I'm pretty confident I extracted it to the correct place.
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Your Python is version 3.6, but you have downloaded Pygame for Python 2.7

Comment: huh. you know where I can get the newest version?

Comment: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/  download it form here

Comment: ah crap I downloaded the one on top thinking it was the newest version. Thanks.

Comment: ya just download cp36 version.

Comment: You can also just enter this in the command-line: `py -3.6 -m pip install pygame`. This will download pygame from PyPI and install it specifically for Python 3.6 and avoids problems with the PATH variable (if Python or the scripts folder are not in the PATH and pip can't be found). (That command works only in Windows.)

Comment: Also, don't extract the .whl manually with 7zip and copy the files to the site-packages directory, use the command-line and enter: `py -3.6 -m pip install name_of_your_wheel.whl` (you have to be in the directory that contains the .whl file).